# Testing truth in particular case. Using docs to write correct input and interpret output

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, calculus

With pencil and paper, I've just shown the following Statement:

```
If... $$z=f(ax+by)$$ then $$b \frac{\partial{z}}{\partial x} -a\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial y} = 0.$$
```

As a Mathematica exercise, I'd like see about verifying this Statement. I have tried to express the Statement with the Input...

```
z := f[a*x + b*y];
0 == b * D[z, x] - a * D[z, y]
```

The Output is...

```
True
```

This is what I'd hope for. My questions stem from my difficulty navigating the documentation:

1. Does my Input correctly represent the Statement?
2. Does the Output mean "the Statement is true"?
3. Where does the documentation answer these questions?
4. How do I find those parts of the documentation for myself next time?

I have done some experiments.

For example, I changed `b` to `2*b`  (just) the 1st line. The Output was...

```
0 == -135 Derivative[1][f][3 x + 90 y].
```

The same change in (just) the 2nd line gave as Output...

```
0 == 135 Derivative[1][f][3 x + 45 y].
```

I'd be concerned if either of these came out zero.

I *guess* these these Outputs are conditions on the Statement: The Statement is true if and only if the condition in the Output is true. I realize these experiments don't tell me if the original Statement is true.

So the questions here are similar:

1. Do I guess correctly?
2. How do I find the documentation that tells me this?

Comment: I tried `b*D[f[a*x+b*y],x]` and it returned `a*b*f'[a*x+b*y]` Then I tried `a*D[f[a*x+b*y],y]` and it returned `a*b*f'[a*x+b*y]` That seems to give some idea why it returned zero when you asked what the difference of these two were. Does that help?

Comment: Yes it gives some idea.
Also just now I asked for the difference with Input...
b* D[z, x] - a * D[z, y]
... and got Output...
0
That also gives me more confidence with the tool.
Your comment seems like an Answer to me.

Comment: I'm happy with the edits by Healyhatman. 
Except a the start of the post after 'I've just shown following Statement' I'm seeing markdown instead of math.